# How to keep back stack with notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, back-stack

I'm trying to present a notification which is handled by a special activity which is not in the normal application flow, and trying to get the back stack handling "correct," meaning:

1. if a notification is handled while the application is running, the notification activity should appear on the current stack, back from the notification should leave us where we were in the application.  Note that this may mean the application is made open.
2. if a notification is handled while the application isn't running, the notification activity should appear on the main (initial) activity of the application.

So far, the code I'm using to present the notification is:

```
/**
 * Show (or update) a notification for the current message set.
 * 
 * @param showNotification true to use a high priority notification which will be immediately
 *                         displayed (as opposed to just added to the status bar)
 */
private void createOrUpdateNotification(boolean showNotification) {
    Message oldest = messages.get(0);
    Message newest = messages.get(messages.size() - 1);

    // Create the notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            // Set notification data and appearance
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(newest.message)
            .setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
            .setWhen(newest.when)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary_color))

            // Set notification options
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .setPriority(showNotification ? NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH : NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(!showNotification);

    // Set up the action if the first (oldest) message has an intent builder
    if(oldest.intent != null) {
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context.getApplicationContext());
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(oldest.intent);
        builder.setContentIntent(stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    }

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(notificationId, builder.build());

    Log.i("notification created");
}
```

For clarification, `Message.intent` is a single intent, configured to open the notification handling activity.

My problem is that if the application is currently running and open when the notification is opened, the application is closed and the notification presented on an empty stack and the application's back stack is cleared out.

My understanding is that the desired behavior should be automatic if the content intent is a pending intent containing a single intent, which is the case here.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did I understand your question correctly? You want to show a notification and stop the thread that issued the notification while its being displayed? Is that what you want?

Comment: No.  The notification is generated by a service.  The content action opens an activity that is out of normal application flow.  When that activity is dismissed, I want to go back to the owning application activity that was interrupted.

Comment: Did you solved that? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

***TaskStackBuilder.create*** will launch a fresh task stack.

Set the content intent like this instead:

```
builder.setContentIntent(
  PendingIntent.getActivity(
    context, 
    0, 
    oldest.intent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very close!  The only thing missing at this point is that if I go back all the way to the launch screen (out of my application) before the notification is generated, then the application isn't started at all, just the notification.

Comment: You can override onBackPressed() for the notification activity and call isTaskRoot(). If the notification activity is the task root, you can then launch your main activity.

Comment: Here's the tricky part, this is all from an SDK (I don't own the host application)  Is there a convenient way to launch the default activity for the application?

Comment: Can I ask which SDK you are using? You can launch the main activity if you know the fully qualified name of the activity (package name and class name). The intent you pass to the pending intent (i.e., oldest.intent) must reference the main activity.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a little bit on @leco's answer, my final solution had two parts.

The first is building the `Notification` as he recommended, using a `PendingIntent` directly instead of trying to use a `TaskStackBuilder`:

```
builder.setContentIntent(
  PendingIntent.getActivity(
    context, 
    0, 
    oldest.intent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
));
```

This got me the correct behavior if the application was running, but not currently open (ie., up until the user hit back all the way out of the application)

To get the "correct" behavior at that point, I modified my `Notification` handling Activity by overriding `finish()`:

```
public void finish() {
    if(isTaskRoot()) {
        // If we're the task root, probably because we were launched from a notification with the
        //  application closed, we should just open the default activity
        try {
            String homeClassName = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName()),
                    0
            ).get(0).activityInfo.name;

            Class homeClass = Class.forName(homeClassName);

            getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), homeClass).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
        }
        catch(Exception exception) {
            Log.w(String.format("Can't find the MAIN activity for package %s", getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
        }
    }
    super.finish();
}
```

The gyrations with `queryIntentActivities` etc are due to the fact that I'm actually developing a drop-in component for applications, so I don't actually know what their root/home/launch activity actually is.  I tried a simpler approach of just building a HOME intent:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName())
```

but for some reason `startActivity` was throwing an exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent
```

even though the `queryIntentActivities` approach demonstrates that there is an appropriate `Activity` for the `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Queue of Bundle and keep adding and removing Bundle Objects from the queue as per your requirement.

```
/**
     * Queue that holds notifications messages
     */
    private Queue<Bundle> mNotificationQueue = new LinkedList<Bundle>();

/**
* Method returning the singleton queue maintained in a static class  
*/
 public Queue<Bundle> getNotificationQueue() {
        return mNotificationQueue;
    }
```

Now when the Notification is received add the notification message to the queue

```
// Fetching the message from intent and adding in bundle to add in the queue

Bundle notificationMsgBundle = intent.getExtras();

notificationMsgBundle.getString(MyConstants.KEY_CHANNEL) + " :: " + notificationMsgBundle.getString(MyConstants.KEY_DATA));
```

DataManager.getInstance().getmNotificationQueue().add(notificationMsgBundle)

Now this static queue is maintained throughout the application and you can remove or add messages from the queue

```
// removing the node message in the queue as per requirement
 DataManager.getInstance().getmNotificationQueue().remove();
```